# mysql convert list of game ids and players to columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

the query...

```
select match_id, player
from player_matches
```

yields the result...

```
match_id  player
1         messi
1         lebron
2         kobe
2         federer
3         serena
3         woods
```

I would like to convert this to...

```
match_id  player_1  player_2
1         messi     lebron
2         kobe      federer
3         serena    woods
```

How can I accomplish this for any fixed number of players per game (e.g. 10 players per game yielding 11 columns)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a dynamic SQL answer that would better fit what you're looking for but here's how you can do it by hardcoding multiple row numbers using `MAX` to pivot your rows to columns:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY match_id ORDER BY match_id) AS RN
  FROM player_matches)
SELECT 
  match_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN player END) AS player_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN player END) AS player_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN player END) AS player_3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN player END) AS player_4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN player END) AS player_5,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN player END) AS player_6,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN player END) AS player_7,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 8 THEN player END) AS player_8,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 9 THEN player END) AS player_9,  
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 10 THEN player END) AS player_10
FROM CTE a
GROUP BY match_id
```

**Result:**

```
| match_id | player_1 | player_2 |
|----------|----------|----------|
| 1        | messi    | lebron   |
| 2        | kobe     | federer  |
| 3        | serena   | woods    |
```

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bXmy0OVA).**